# Frapi API Documentation Page not workign

Tags: php, api, rest, frapi

Frapi API Documentation Page not workign properly after i have synchronize.
but all other things are perfectly working.
only the API Documentation Page load half way through.

Comment: no i need to know the resonfor this

Comment: this is the error i am getting

Comment: PHP Notice error, with message: Undefined index: name (Error Number: 8), (File: /home/ingrisi/public_html/api/src/frapi/custom/Output/html/Introduction.html.tpl at line 324),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have finaly found the solotion for this.
the resons is frapi coded for a single parameter action if we put multipel parameters this problem occour.

to prevent this problem change the code of  custom/Output/html/Introduction.html.tpl file like this page.

https://github.com/trevormorse/frapi/commit/878d5e002557fef0b9abb9ec82c9895ac6688b86

Comment: Yup, that is the fix.